# Can ActiveMQ CPP Api be used to Talk to RabbitMQ Broker?

Tags: c++, activemq-classic, rabbitmq, amqp, activemq-cpp

We have C++ Software that needs to send message via RabbitMQ broker, has somebody tried ActiveMQ CPP lib (CMS) to send/receive messages to RabbitMQ broker?

Answer (score 3):

the [CMS API](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/) is a generic API for messaging which supports a number of different providers. There's nothing stopping someone implementing the CMS API on top of some AMQP C client library for example.

However since CMS supports Stomp it should be possible to communicate with RabbitMQ as well as pretty much any other JMS provider via [StompConnect](http://stomp.codehaus.org/StompConnect)

Answer (score 1):

You can expose RabbitMQ using the STOMP protocol. That means that you can interact (consume/produce) with RabbitMQ with clients written in any platform (even using Telnet).

Answer (score -2):

these are two different messaging systems that are incompatible with each other.